# Laravel . Using two controllers in the same view

Tags: php, laravel, view, model, controller

I am really new to laravel.  So i am just working on a simple project.  I built a Postscontroller that has it's views . So the problem is i wanna extend this to having comments in the view_one_post.blade.php view.
So i should create CommentsController but i am not sure how to list the comments using CommentsController@index and i am not sure what view this method should return because i am using the comments in the same view of posts which is view_one_post.blade.php ?
I have seen some answers to this question but it just doesn't match my case

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could look into making a view just for the comments and a View Composer to give it the data, then you can include that comments view anywhere you need those comments

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add the code for your `Postscontroller` method and the code for the blade file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with a View Composer. You can create a view for the comments which can be included in any other views. A View Composer will allow you to bind data to this view before it is rendered.

```
use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class CommentsComposer
{
    protected $comment;

    public function __construct(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('comments', $this->comment->latest()->take(10)->get());
    }
}
```

In a Service Provider's `boot` method you can attach the composer to your view:

```
View::composer('partials.commments', 'App\Composers\CommentsComposer');
```

Anywhere you want to use that view you can just include it in Blade:

```
@include('partials.comments')
```

This allows you to have an isolated place for the logic of handling the data that is needed for this view partial and it only needs to worry about that one responsibility. Unlike a Controller a Composer doesn't need to worry about handling the request or response.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Views - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) `View::composer`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Blade - Including Subviews](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#including-subviews) `@include`